# Flutter Cast To function like on Youtube

Tags: flutter, casting

I have a Flutter app containing a Video with [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) and [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie). I want to implement something to cast that video to a TV, like on Youtube (image below).

Does anyone know how I can implement that? Is there a package supporting that exact functionality? I can also use another video player package, like [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). I actually checked that package for that exact functionality, but didn't find it. Did I oversee something?

[image]